# C char** to char[] after string split

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

I'm trying to store char,after string split of input argument by ',', into char[] array. Now this is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
 char *function= NULL;
 //The function is a parameter in the format function_name,par1,par2..
 function=argv[4];
 char** tokens;
 tokens = str_split(function, ',');

 if (tokens)
{
 int i;
 char *function_name;
 char arguments[10];

 for (i = 0; *(tokens + i); i++)
 {
    printf("function=[%s]\n",*(tokens + i));
    if(i==0)
    {
        function_name=*(tokens + i);
        printf("function_name: %s\n",function_name);
    }
    else
    {
       arguments[i-1]=*(tokens + i);
    }
    free(*(tokens + i));
  }

  if(strcmp("PKCS7SignML",function_name))
 {
  const char *pin_number=arguments[0];
  printf("pin: %s\n",pin);
  unsigned long slot_number=atol(arguments[1]);
  printf("slot_number: %lu\n",slot_number);
  const char *szInputFileName=arguments[2];
  printf("szInputFileName: %c\n",szInputFileName);
  const char *szOutputFileName=arguments[3]);
  printf("szOutputFileName: %c\n",szOutputFileName);
  int bInitialize=atoi(arguments[4]);
  printf("bInitialize: %d\n",bInitialize);
 }
```

But when I try to print the values that are char, the values are empty.

How can I fix this?

Comment: what is str_split? is it your own function? if yes post code for that too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't compile your code but there is an obvious error here:

```
 char arguments[10];
```

then your do:

```
       arguments[i-1]=*(tokens + i);
```

You are writing a pointer into a char.

EDIT: I have made your code compile, there were several errors. For example, you free the pointers too early.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

char** str_split(char* a_str, const char a_delim)
{
char** result    = 0;
size_t count     = 0;
char* tmp        = a_str;
char* last_comma = 0;
char delim[2];

    delim[0] = a_delim;
    delim[1] = 0;

    while (*tmp)
    {
        if (a_delim == *tmp)
        {
            count++;
            last_comma = tmp;
        }
        tmp++;
    }

    /* Add space for trailing token. */
    count += last_comma < (a_str + strlen(a_str) - 1);

    /* Add space for terminating null string so caller
    knows where the list of returned strings ends. */
    count++;


    result = malloc(sizeof(char*) * count);

    if (result)
    {
        size_t idx  = 0;
        char* token = strtok(a_str, delim);

        while (token)
        {
            assert(idx < count);
            *(result + idx++) = strdup(token);
            token = strtok(0, delim);
        }
        assert(idx == count - 1);
        *(result + idx) = 0;
    }

    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
 int i;
 char *function= NULL;
     //The function is a parameter in the format function_name,par1,par2..
     function=argv[4];
     char** tokens;
     tokens = str_split(function, ',');

    if (tokens)
    {
    char *function_name;
    char *arguments[10];

        for (i = 0; *(tokens + i); i++)
        {
            printf("function=[%s]\n",*(tokens + i));
            if (i==0)
            {
                function_name=*(tokens + i);
                printf("function_name: %s\n",function_name);
            }
            else
            {
                arguments[i-1]=*(tokens + i);
            }
        }

        if (strcmp("PKCS7SignML",function_name))
        {
        const char *pin_number=arguments[0];
        unsigned long slot_number=atol(arguments[1]);
        const char *szInputFileName=arguments[2];
        const char *szOutputFileName=arguments[3];
        int bInitialize=atoi(arguments[4]);

            printf("pin: %s\n",pin_number);
            printf("slot_number: %lu\n",slot_number);
            printf("szInputFileName: %s\n",szInputFileName);
            printf("szOutputFileName: %s\n",szOutputFileName);
            printf("bInitialize: %d\n",bInitialize);
        }
    }
    i =0;
    while (tokens[i]) {
        free(tokens[i++]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning values of type `char *` to array elements whose type is `char`.  Later you treat those same array elements as if they were each whole `char` arrays or pointers to such.  My best guess, therefore, is that you want to declare `arguments` differently:

```
// An array of 10 pointers to char:
char *arguments[10];
```

Furthermore, after assigning each element of `tokens` to a variable or array member, you *free* that pointer.  You need to understand that freeing a pointer is about the *value* of the pointer and the memory it points to, not about the *variable*, if any, where the pointer value is stored.  Freeing those pointers invalidates all copies of them, including the ones you just finished assigning.  That is clearly not what you actually want, because you attempt later to dereference those pointers.

Answer (score 0):

This is my str_split function:

```
char** str_split(char* a_str, const char a_delim)
{
 char** result    = 0;
 size_t count     = 0;
 char* tmp        = a_str;
 char* last_comma = 0;
 char delim[2];
 delim[0] = a_delim;
 delim[1] = 0;

 while (*tmp)
 {
    if (a_delim == *tmp)
    {
        count++;
        last_comma = tmp;
    }
    tmp++;
 }

/* Add space for trailing token. */
count += last_comma < (a_str + strlen(a_str) - 1);

/* Add space for terminating null string so caller
   knows where the list of returned strings ends. */
count++;

result = malloc(sizeof(char*) * count);

if (result)
{
    size_t idx  = 0;
    char* token = strtok(a_str, delim);

    while (token)
    {
        assert(idx < count);
        *(result + idx++) = strdup(token);
        token = strtok(0, delim);
    }
    assert(idx == count - 1);
    *(result + idx) = 0;
}

 return result;
}
```

Now I correct the declaration of char arguments[10]; into:

```
char *arguments[10];
```

and removed the 'free(tokens);' statement row, but when I run the code, it not goes into

```
if(strcmp("PKCS7SignML",function_name))
```

Comment: edited my answer, for the strcmp you need to check it against 0 with !strcmp if you are looking for identical string.

Answer (score 0):

With Dominique's suggestion I solved the problem.

The two important errors were:

1.`free(*(tokens + i));`
   Called before reading values in arguments[i]. So when I try to access to the char source pointed to, it's value was null.

2.`if(strcmp("PKCS7SignML",function_name)==0)`
The strcmp function return 0 if str1 is equal to str2 [strcmp() function](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm)